# ncftpput gl_getline(): not interactive, use stdio

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to upload a folder and it's contents to a server of mine using bitbuckets pipelines. When I run this command:

```
ncftpput -avR -u "azure-ci" *server-ip* dist/cardsortsoftwares/* C:/cardsortsoftwares.net
```

I consistently get the same error, no matter what variations of the command I try.

```
*** Error: gl_getline(): not interactive, use stdio.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in my case, I was missing the -p flag.
-p is required in non-interactive environments if you use the -u flag. adding either the -p flag or removing the -u flag solved my issue